# Use quicksand with non-fixed height/width container

Tags: jquery, html, css, quicksand, jquery-easing

Is there a way to use the Quicksand plugin (http://razorjack.net/quicksand/) with a container which is set to percentage dimensions rather than fixed? It functions fine but the animations don't work properly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and used some jQuery to fix the dimensions based on what they are on the screen

```
    var thumbHeight = $('.project-thumb').height(),
    thumbWidth = $('.project-thumb').outerWidth();                  

    $('.project-thumb').css({'max-width':thumbWidth, 'max-height':thumbHeight});
```